# Is there a quick way to compare two equally formatted tables in SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql, compare

I would like to make an SQL query to compare two tables with identical columns, both names and types. Each table has a unique key. I want the query to return any rows that contain unequal values. I know could do something like this

```
select * 
from table_1, table_2
where 
table_1.key = table_2.key
and (
 table_1.col1 != table_2.col1 OR
 table_1.col2 != table_2.col2 OR
 ...

)
```

but this would be tedious since there are a large and potentially variable number of columns.

**edit**

If it helps, I'm using a tsql system.

Comment: good question.  In addition to your example, you would want to verify there are no ID columns in one table that don't exist in the other.

However, your example is exactly how I would approach the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what type of DB you are using but if you are using SQL Server 2005 or higher try this:

```
select 'table1' as tblName, *  from
  (select * from table1
   except
   select * from table2) x
union all
select 'table2' as tblName, *  from
  (select * from table2
   except select * 
   from table1) x
```

Answer (score 1):

How abt this..

```
select * from table1 where not exists (select * from table2)
union all
select * from table2 where not exists (select * from table1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Verified with SQL Server:

```
(select * from table1 except select * from table2)
    union
(select * from table2 except select * from table1);
```

Verified with Oracle:

```
(select * from table1 minus (select * from table2))
    union
(select * from table2 minus (select * from table1))
```